# Why does Discord let webhooks get deleted with a simple delete request?

Tags: security, discord

Why does Discord let you delete a webhook with a simple delete request, such as from `requests.delete` in Python? Isn't that a security problem, because anyone can delete it if they have the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bare ["delete webhook"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#delete-webhook) endpoint requires authentication and the proper permissions. The ["delete webhook with token"](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#delete-webhook-with-token) endpoint doesn't require authentication, but that's because the URL itself contains the webhook's secure token. And you shouldn't be sharing that with anyone, the same way you wouldn't share your bot token or your login password.

So yes, technically there's a URL that anyone, if they know it, could send a delete request to. But that URL's not listed publicly anywhere, and only those with permissions to delete the webhook should have access to it in the first place.